# Meteorjs how much of a real time is it really?

Tags: meteor, real-time

I had my chance to play with this tool for a while now and made a chat application instead of a hello world. My project has 2 meteor applications sharing the same mongo database:

- client
- operator

when I type a message from the operator console it sometimes takes as much as 7-8 seconds to appear to the subscribed client. So my question is...how much of a real time can I expect from this meteor? Right now I can see better results with other services such as pubnub or pusher.

Should the delay come from the fact that it's 2 applications subscribed to the same db?

P.S. I need 2 applications because the client and operator apps are totally different mostly in design and media libraries (css/jquery plugins etc.) which is the only way I found to make the client app much lighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use two databases without DDP your apps are not going to operate in real time. You should either use one complete app or use DDP to relay messages to the other instance (via Meteor.connect)

This is a bit of an issue for the moment if you want to do the subscription on the server as there isn't really server to server ddp support with subscriptions yet. So you need to use the client to make the subscription:

```
connection = Meteor.connect("http://YourOtherMetorInstanceUrl");

connection.subscribe("messages");
```

Instead of

```
Meteor.subscribe("messages");
```

In your client app, of course using the same subscription names as you do for your corresponding publish functions on the other meteor instance

Comment: `My project has 2 meteor applications sharing the same mongo database:` same database. Does it stil apply what u said here?

Answer (score 2):

Akshat's answer is good, but there's a bit more explanation of why:

When Meteor is running it adds an [observer](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) to the collection, so any changes to data in that collection are immediately reactive. But, if you have two applications writing to the same database (and this is how you are synchronizing data), the observer is not in place. So it's not going to be fully real-time.

However, the server does regularly poll the database for outside changes, hence the 7-8 second delay.

It looks like your applications are designed this way to overcome the limitation Meteor has right now where all client code is delivered to all clients. Fixing this is on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo).

In the mean time, in addition to Akshat's suggestion, I would also recommend using Meteor methods to insert messages. Then from client application, use `Meteor.call('insertMessage', options ...` to add messages via [DDP](http://meteor.com/blog/2012/03/21/introducing-ddp), which will keep the application real-time.

You would also want to separate the databases.

Comment: Looks like I will need to eliminate most of my client's server code and simply call methods on the operator's server via that connect.